# Magento 2.1.9 Shipment not save in admin side

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, shipping, authorize.net

I have place order and using authorize.net payment method.I have facing this issue in admin side when save shipment  getting this error

```
Cannot save shipment.exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:316 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(316): PDO->commit() 
#1 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(510): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_commit() 
#2 /home/apps2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(253): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->commit()
```

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14110

Comment: already i try this but not getting success

Comment: @RvSingh, Are you working on Local Environment ?

Comment: No,I am not working local environment,  i am working on developer mode

Comment: @SanjayGohil Dear I am not using local env. Please look at my question.